# Результат вывода примера на С

Tags: c

Почему результат длина массива русских букв выводит `13`, если смотреть таблицу *iso_8859-5* то там `dec` совсем другой, а у меня получается отрицательные значения. Знак `!` всё правильно вывел.

```
   int strlen(char s[]);

     main(){
       char msg[] = "Привет!";
        printf("%s %d\n", msg, strlen(msg));
      }


     int strlen(char s[]){
        int i;
        i = 0;
        while (s[i] != '\0'){
         printf("%d\n",s[i]);
         ++i;}
         return i;
      }
```

Результат:

> -48
>   -97
>   -47
>   -128
>   -48
>   -72
>   -48
>   -78
>   -48
>   -75
>   -47
>   -126
>   33
>   Привет! 13

Comment: Какая у Вас ОС?

Comment: Это utf8, а не iso8859-5.

Comment: debian 6.0.7.

Comment: кто знает просто поясните почему так. только не смотрите с высока)

Comment: И кстати, у вас UB: вы выводите `char` как будто это `signed int`.

Comment: @avdoshkin: А что именно непонятно? Ваша строка «Привет!» не в iso8859-5, а в utf-8. Отрицательные значения берутся потому, что (1) вы используете неправильный спецификатор формата, (2) на вашей систем `char` == `signed char`.

Comment: @avdoshkin, почитайте про [UTF-8](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), тут вроде неплохо все описано.

Если коротко и про Ваш случай, то русские буквы занимают по 2 байта (кстати, это те, которые у вас отрицательные числа), а ascii символы 1 байт.